# Unable to reference Windows IoT in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-iot-core

When I upgraded Visual Studio 2017 to 15.8.2 it crashed and I had to wipe everything and reload.  Since then I have not been able to get the Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP.  When I click on the reference in my project the Windows IoT Extension shows up with a yellow triangle.  I right click on reference to add reference, go to universal windows (it shows core and extensions), I click extensions and Windows IoT is not there.  I've uninstalled and installed VS2017 many times and I think I'm following the IoT instructions to the letter on the install but obviously I'm being thick and missing something.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp iot">
  <Identity Name="3ac96fd1-69de-454f-a811-1b1ac668e762" Publisher="CN=kbown" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="3ac96fd1-69de-454f-a811-1b1ac668e762" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>Water_Dewater</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>kbown</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"          EntryPoint="Water_Dewater.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="Water_Dewater" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="Water_Dewater" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <iot:Capability Name="lowLevelDevices" />
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="109b86ad-f53d-4b76-aa5f-821e2ddf2141" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4MkW.png)

Comment: Hi Bonus9500, the iot extension enable Windows.System.SystemManagementContract access, can you try add system management in package.appxmanifest as a replacement to see if it helps? And the VS2017 15.8.6 and 15.8.4 both have not this issue. What's your OS version?

Comment: Thank you Rita for taking the time to try and help me.  I'm running VS2017 15.8.5 and Windows 10 1803.  I've attached my package.appxmanifest.  I tried your suggestion but nothing changed.  Even if I download an MS solution like Blinky, I cannot get the Windows IoT extension to show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP will be installed on the following path via [Windows Software Development Kit(SDK)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

[image]

After installation complete, you can check in control panel.

[image]

You can try to install SDK to see if it helps.

Update:

[image]

Comment: I look up the control panel and 10.0.17134.12 was already there.  However, I installed the kit as recommended but it did not provide results.  One curious entry was
Windows Software Development Kit - Windows 10.0.26624  I don't know where that came from.

Comment: @Bonus9500 You can check from Visual Studio Installer to see SDK is installed or not. See my update snapshot in the answer. If not, you can add and update your VS2017 to see if it helps.

Comment: Hey Rita.  I had to install all of the Windows 10 SDK v10240.0 through to 17134.0 and now it works.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't think all of the SDKs need to be installed but if your local environment has some problem may cause the SDK installation has a problem. You can uninstall SDK one by one to see which modify the this path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Extension SDKs\WindowsIoT`